# SocketIO emitting message to rooms doesn't work correctly

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io

I'm creating an app that allows users to have conversations with other individual users.
As a user in the app, whenever someone I have a conversation with, is connecting to the app, I would like to get a message alerting me he is online.
For that purpose, I'm using node.js with socketIO and react.

The way I implemented the following in my server is:

```
const socketio = require('socket.io');
const io = socketio(server);

io.on('connection', async (socket) => {
    const { user } = socket.request;

    const userConversationIds = user.conversations;
    socket.join(conversationIds);

    let ioToConversations = io;
    userConversationIds.forEach((conversationId) => {
        ioToConversations = ioToConversations.to(conversationId);
    });

    ioToConversations.emit('online', `${user.firstName} ${user.lastName} is now online!`);
});
```

and on the client-side:

```
import io from 'socket.io-client';
const socket = io();

componentDidMount () => {
    socket.on('online', (messageText) => {
        console.log(messageText); // eslint-disable-line 
    });
};
```

All of the above resulted in a "user in now online" message, **only** to the **now-connected-user** itself.
I would want the **other users in the conversation** to have that message, and the connected user itself to have **none**.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

One mistake could be that you didn't connect to the server properly, you need to connect using this code and replacing `<port>` with your port number assuming that you are running locally:
`io.connect("http://localhost:<port>")`

Another mistake could be that you didn't used the method `.io()` and `.emit()` at the same time. What i mean by that is that you used the `.emit()` method after the forEach loop. You could try doing this instead:

```
io.on("connection", async (socket) => {
  const { user } = socket.request;
  const userConversationIds = user.conversations;

  let ioToConversations = io;

  userConversationIds.forEach((conversationId) => {
    ioToConversations = ioToConversations
      .to(conversationId)
      .emit("online", `${user.firstName} ${user.lastName} is now online!`);
  });
});
```

Another error could be because you didn't make the socket of each user join the specific rooms with the `.join()` method. You could do it with the following:

```
userConversationIds.forEach((conversationId) => {
    socket.join(conversationId);
  });
```

This code should be placed before the `forEach` loop that emits the message.
You could also join and emit at the same, however i have not tested with the following:

```
userConversationIds.forEach((conversationId) => {
    socket.join(conversationId);

    ioToConversations = ioToConversations
      .to(conversationId)
      .emit("online", `${user.firstName} ${user.lastName} is now online!`);
  });
```

Comment: I shortened the code the to relevant section but the socket DOES connects to server, as it does triggers the 'online' event, but just to the irrelevant user it meant to be shown.

Comment: also, I did joined to the rooms, only that I forgot to add it to the code here, sorry! edited.

Comment: perhaps you can keep an array in the database of the users who are supposed to receive it and loop through each to join the specific rooms.